# Debian 10.6 boots to black screen; "no screens found(EE) in log"

Tags: debian, x11, drivers, video, macintosh

I have installed Debian 10.6 "Buster" on a 2019 5k iMac, but the system boots to a black screen with a flashing cursor in the upper-left corner.  I can still get to a console, however.

In looking at `/var/log/Xorg.o.log`, I see the following errors:

```
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
(II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
(II) UnloadModule: "amdgpu"
(EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
(EE) Fatal server error: no screens found(EE)
```

I generated an `xorg.conf` file by running `X -configure` and copied it to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but got the same results. The only difference is that before, `Xorg.0.log` contained a long list of informational messages about the various supported GPUs with the AMDGPU driver, whereas now it just says `All GPUs supported by the amdgpu kernel driver.`

I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the screen, not the driver, because booting with an Ubuntu Live DVD works fine (I presume it uses the same amdgpu driver).  But I don't really know how to modify Xorg's config, change the driver, or change the screen config.

Typing `dpkg-reconfigure -Phigh xserver-xorg` does literally nothing.

I've been searching on this issue for a while, but all I see are posts from literally 10-15 years ago.  Most of the information in those posts are irrelevant now, and I don't know enough about the low-level nuts and bolts of X configuration to adapt any of it to modern times.

How do I fix this?